# How to make output directory selection panel?

Tags: java, image, swing

Hi I am trying to make one pane that shows something like windows explorer in my computer.
when user complete it's operations, and after that when he want to save edited image at specific place on disk then he can easily select directory from that pane.
i want to design something like this :

[image]

is it possible to do something like that ?
my picture editor looks like :

[image]

at right side of editor i want to put something like output directory selection pane.

> is anyone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes its possible.  It's basically just `JTree`.

You will probably want to take a look at [`File#listRoots`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots%28%29), [`File#isDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) and [`File#listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29).

You'll also want to take a look at [How to use trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html).

You'll probably also want to take a look at [`FileSystemView#getSystemIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemIcon%28java.io.File%29) which will allow you to look an appropriate icon for the given `File`

However, it might be simpler to just use a [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) ;)

Comment: Yes sir i have referred example of [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TreeDemoProject/src/components/TreeDemo.java) but how to load whole computer directory system in it i can't understand because how to add directory inside directory and file inside directory. i am confused about it. if you can guide me then i will be so thankful to you.

Comment: The "basic" idea is to do a lazy loading process.  Start by loading the `File` roots.  When a node is expanded, you will want to check to see if it has begin loaded or not.  If it hasn't, you will want to do `File#listFiles` to load all the files/directories for the selected node. You may want to have a read through [How to Write a Tree-Will-Expand Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treewillexpandlistener.html) and probably [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: yes sir with File and it's operation like loading file from disk and loading directory from disk i am working from last 1 year but in web applications and all  but i am new in desktop based so that's why i am facing such a problem but i am sure that within 2-3 days i will learn JTree completely. and thanks for guidance. if i will face any problem then i will post it.

Answer (score 6):

A complete example using `JTree` is examined in [`FileBrowser`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/6692).

[image: jtree image]

An alternative using `Outline` is shown [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).

[image: outline image]

Comment: yes sir i am referring that example from last 10 minute. i don't have to implement all thing like that but i am trying to digest whatever i need from it and thank for help.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at JFileChooser. 
You can use this object to open a SaveDialog and get a save path on the local harddisk.
Then eventually use an ObjectOutputStream to write a file.

Sample code:

```
    JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser();
    c.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    // Demonstrate "Save" dialog:
    int rVal = c.showSaveDialog(fb);
    if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println(c.getSelectedFile().toString());
    }
```

Comment: yes i know that because i have used this as image browse from directory but i want something like the picture posted above.

Comment: Then you might want to have a look at JTree

Comment: Excellent :) shout out if you need further help

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled with a JFileChooser, sorry if it's not the solution you're looking for

Note: you say choose a directory but I assume you mean that they can name their file

```
private File selectSaveFile() {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("File Type", "txt"));
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(frame);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        return fc.getSelectedFile();
    }
    //the user didn't click save if we are here
    return null;
}
```