# How to recursively expand JTable cell entries into a tree

Tags: java, swing, tree, jtable

I'd like to add a file-explorer type of drop down list/tree to a JTable populated with Strings. When I click on a table cell which contains a string of info, I'd like it to expand to show other information related to the string. I'm not asking for any code solutions, but rather a pointer about which type of built-in Java language feature(s) to use to accomplish this goal. Thanks.

Comment: MouseListener and JWindow or use in the inbuilt tooltip support of the JTable and its cell renderers

Comment: Maybe one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18441935/230513)?

Comment: i believe swingx has a tree table you could use, hopefully that fits whats you need